# How to redirect all methods of a contained class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas, composition

How to implement the composition pattern? I have a class `Container` which has an attribute object `Contained`. I would like to  redirect/allow access to all methods of `Contained` class from `Container` by simply calling `my_container.some_contained_method()`. Am I doing the right thing in the right way?

I use something like:

```
class Container:
   def __init__(self):
       self.contained = Contained()
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       if item in self.__dict__: # some overridden
           return self.__dict__[item] 
       else:
           return self.contained.__getattr__(item) # redirection
```

**Background:**

I am trying to build a class (`Indicator`) that adds to the functionality of an existing class (`pandas.DataFrame`). `Indicator` will have all the methods of `DataFrame`. I could use *inheritance*, but I am following the "favor *composition* over *inheritance*" advice (see, e.g., the answers in: [python: inheriting or composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389816/python-inheriting-or-composition)). One reason not to inherit is because the base class is not serializable and I need to serialize.

I have found [this](http://yauhen.yakimovich.info/blog/tag/composition/), but I am not sure if it fits my needs.

Comment: And how is a proxy object going to help your serialisation  - you'll still have to do that somehow... Just inherit from the base (because your object "is-a") and work from there...

Comment: A `pandas.DataFrame` has a lot of methods which return another `DataFrame`. It may be hard to arrange for your `Container` to return another `Container`...

Comment: @Jon the base class is not serializalbe, but picklable. It is easier to extend the pickling of a component than that of a super class.

Comment: @unutbu, good point. I guess I could wrap every returned `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Caveats:

- DataFrames have a lot of attributes. If a `DataFrame` attribute is a number, you probably just want to return that number. But if the `DataFrame` attribute is `DataFrame` you probably want to return a `Container`. What should we do if the `DataFrame` attribute is a `Series` or a descriptor? To implement `Container.__getattr__` properly, you really
  have to write unit tests *for each and every attribute*.
- Unit testing is also needed for `__getitem__`.
- You'll also have to define and unit test `__setattr__` and `__setitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, etc.
- Pickling is a form of serialization, so if `DataFrames` are picklable, I'm not sure how `Container`s really help with serialization.

Some comments:

- `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute is not in `self.__dict__`. So you do not need `if item in self.__dict__` in your `__getattr__`.
- `self.contained.__getattr__(item)` calls `self.contained`'s
  `__getattr__` method directly. That is usually not what you want to
  do, because it circumvents the whole Python attribute lookup
  mechanism. For example, it ignores the possibility that the attribute
  could be in `self.contained.__dict__`, or in the `__dict__` of one of
  the bases of `self.contained.__class__` or if `item` refers to a
  descriptor. Instead use `getattr(self.contained, item)`.

---

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

def tocontainer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return Container(result)
    return wrapper

class Container(object):
   def __init__(self, df):
       self.contained = df
   def __getitem__(self, item):
       result = self.contained[item]
       if isinstance(result, type(self.contained)):
           result = Container(result)
       return result
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       result = getattr(self.contained, item)
       if callable(result):
           result = tocontainer(result)
       return result
   def __repr__(self):
       return repr(self.contained)
```

Here is some random code to test if -- at least superficially -- `Container` delegates to `DataFrame`s properly and returns `Containers`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1),(2,2,)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df = Container(df)
df['col1'][3] = 0
print(df)
#    col1  col2
# 0     1     2
# 1     1     3
# 2     1     4
# 3     2     1
# 4     2     2
gp = df.groupby('col1').aggregate(np.count_nonzero)
print(gp)
#       col2
# col1      
# 1        3
# 2        2
print(type(gp))
# <class '__main__.Container'>

print(type(gp[gp.col2 > 2]))
# <class '__main__.Container'>

tf = gp[gp.col2 > 2].reset_index()
print(type(tf))
# <class '__main__.Container'>

result = df[df.col1 == tf.col1]
print(type(result))
# <class '__main__.Container'>
```

Comment: Could you also explain why this is preferable (or not) over inheritance?

Comment: This is very helpful. I couldn't find a good discussion of this elsewhere.

Comment: @user1579844: If class B *extends* class A by adding new methods and does not override class A's methods, then use inheritance. Use inheritance if `B` can be substituted wherever `A` is used. Use composition for dependency injection (to allow class `B` to have a class `A2` instead of a class `A`). For this and other ideas, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/190597). And sometimes neither composition or inheritance is right -- sometimes a simple function is best. (I rather wonder if that is the case here.)

Comment: @unutbu, if I go for the simple function solution, how do I customize myindicator.plot(), for example?

Comment: @user1579844: You would define `def myplot(dataframe): ...` as a module-level function.

Comment: This also doesn't extend to double underscore methods like `__add__` and so on

Answer (score 1):

I found unbutbu 's answer very useful for my own application,  I ran into issues displaying it properly in a jupyter notebook.  I found that adding the following methods to the class solved the issue.

```
def _repr_html_(self):
    return self.contained._repr_html_()

def _repr_latex_(self):
    return self.contained._repr_latex_()
```